# Xcode: how to re-arrange elements not auto-moved to the center?

Tags: xcode, uiview, xcode4, interface-builder, xcode4.2

When I try to re-arrange the elements in Xcode 4.2 interface builder (put something as a subview of another etc.) it places elements in the center, not preserving it's current position.

Is it possible to re-arrange the elements in Interface Builder with preserving their position in main UIView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely possible to rearrange elements in the way you want.  The best you can do is to select one or more elements and choose Editor > Embed In > View.  That will put the selected elements in a new `UIView` without changing the on-screen position of the elements.  But the new `UIView` will not tightly wrap the embedded elements.